# Jquery – scroll function affects click function

Tags: jquery, function, click, slidetoggle

I have been trying for a long time to fix this problem without lock so I try in here again and hope someone can help me.  I have this code...

```
$(window).trigger('scroll'); // init the value

$(window).on('scroll', function(){
    var pos = $('#subHeadline').offset();
    $('.article-header').each(function(){
        if (pos.top >= $(this).offset().top && pos.top <= $(this).next().offset().top) {
            $('#subHeadline').html($(this).html()); 
            return; 
        }
    });
    $('button').on('click', function () {
        $(this).text($(this).text() == '(–)' ? '(+)' : '(–)');
        $('.description' ).slideToggle('fast');
    });
});
```

When I click the slidetoggle and scroll the (–) change to (+) can anybody tell me why that is happening? I'm new to jquery so please let me know if this is nonsense.. I have tried to provide a Fiddle but I could'nt get it to work. But the website is www.runebs.dk (code:Rune) so you can check the code in there.

Many thanks!

Comment: When using jquery selectors `$('')` you should always cache your result in a variable so you aren't making multiple calls to create the same object: `$(window)` becomes `var $window = $(window);` and is used the same. `$window.trigger('scroll');`

Comment: thanks for the hint.. If i understand you correct should i call the second $(window).on('scroll', function() { something else?

Comment: Yes, `$(window).on...` becomes `$window.on...`. Using `$('')` creates an object and you are just storing that object inside of a variable, named $window for this example. So any place you need to use $(window) you can now use $window without creating another object, using less resources and making your code more DRY (don't repeat yourself).

Comment: Yes that make sense thank you.. Do you have any ideas of what the problem with the slidetoggle can be?

Comment: Try moving `$('button').on...` outside of the `$(window).on...` function. Clicking the toggle is not related to the window scrolling so it should be called as a stand alone event listener.

Comment: It looks like it is working now?

Comment: No it still change when you scroll.

Comment: In the live page, the button HTML is still invalid. Which script is your javascript in?

Comment: Yes I know that, I'm working local so I haven't updated it.. But I will do that right away.. The javascript is in the footer in the script.js file..

Answer (score 0):

Theres a couple problems here:

1. Youre HTML is invalid:

Old code:

```
<h3><button id"button1">(+)</button></h3>
```

Should be:

```
<button id="button1">(+)</button></h3>
//  also nesting a button inside an H3 tag is symantically incorrect,
//  but that's not a big deal
```

1. You aren't selecting the button correctly:

Old Code:

```
 $('button').on('click', function () {
```

Should be:

```
 $('#button1').on('click', function () { //or whatever the button ID is
```

Comment: Thank you. I have made the corrections but it the (+) (–) is still triggered when i scroll..

Comment: it funny when i make the corrections the slidetoggle doesn't work.. do you have any idea of what that could be.. ?

Comment: Did you change `id"button1"` to `id="button1"`?

Comment: I have tried to make the slideToggle as the other one i'm using.. So instead of a button my html is `<h3><a href="#" id="description">(+)</a></h3>`.. But that doesn't work either.. Could it be something with the `<div class="description">` is inside the `<header class="article-header">`?